Create multiple rows from single row file using Spark in Java
Looking for a solution to create multiple rows based on the length of a string from a single row text file.
Example:
001XXXXXXXXXX002YYYYYYYYYY003ZZZZZZZZZZ004AAAAAAAAAA
Expected output if we consider length of string for each row is 13 ( One row change to 4 rows)
|        ROW|
-------------
001XXXXXXXXXX

002YYYYYYYYYY

003ZZZZZZZZZZ

004AAAAAAAAAA

I am able to do it by single dataframe using df.first() to get the entire row, next converting entire string value to multiple Row object and put into list, next create new Data set from the list.
As per my understanding it not an efficient process and looking better solution as single row can hold 1GB data.
